# Is it possible to ddrescue only image files (jpg, png, etc.)

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, ddrescue

I have a corrupted NTFS partition. I am trying to use `ddrescue` on the same from ubuntu 20.10 liveUSB.

The command I am planning to use is this

```
sudo ddrescue -n -r 1 -c 16 /dev/sda4 /media/restored.img ~/status.log
```

I have very limited knowledge about file systems, partitions and how `ddrescue` works. And I learn from old threads that `ddrescue` can take a very long time in the order of several days.

I wanted to know if there is a way to rescue just image files (pictures- jpg, png, etc.,)? I may be completely wrong, but can such a method (if exists) reduce the rescue time?

Comment: `ddrescue` isn't for rescuing files.   It is for making an image copy of block device (or, sometimes, a specific file - usually a disk image file), in an attempt to recover as much of the data as possible.  It is useful when the block device is dying or not-quite-dead-yet but is still somewhat readable (albeit with frequent read errors).

Comment: Thanks. Then I am headed in the wrong direction. Will testdisk help in my case? (Suggested in the answer below)

Comment: yes, `testdisk` or its companion program `photorec`.   BTW, I would first use `ddrescue` to recover as much of the NTFS filesystem as possible, and then use testdisk/photorec on the rescued image copy.  The first rule of  recovering files from a corrupted filesystem or failing drive is "never work on the original, always work on a copy".   And, ideally, work on a copy of the copy just in case you mess it up and have to start over (or, if you use a snapshot-capable filesystem like ZFS, take a snapshot of the image copy before you do anything - you can always rollback to the snapshot).

Comment: Best of all, though, is to avoid getting into a situation where you need to use tools like this - and the only way to do that is to make regular backups.  Too late for that now, but you'll need to remember this in future.   **Data that is not backed up is data that you are willing to risk losing**.  Also note: raid is not a substitute for backup. RAID (and raid-like filesystems like btrfs or zfs) is  a convenience to minimise the number of times that you need to restore from a backup, but even raid is subject to fire / flood / theft and even failure of an entire batch of drives in the arrray.

Comment: "I have very limited knowledge about file systems, partitions and how `ddrescue` works" – In case you want to change this, see [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1090647/432690), especially from where it says "answering additional questions" for the first time.

Comment: Thanks. Sure I will read that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cas explained in comments, `dd rescue` cannot just rescue image files (or any specific file type), it is used for making image copies of block devices. If block device is not corrupt then it can also copy a particular file from block device just like `dd` command. What you can use is `testdisk` command. Run `sudo testdisk`, then select the disk in which corrupted partition is, then select the partition table type (best to leave it default) then select the `[Advanced] Filesystem Utils` option, then select the corrupted partition and select `Undelete` option, then it will list all the files it finds in that partiton. Keep in mind there might be lot of files so it might take a while. Also if your partition is not being listed, then you can try to analyse the disk for any lost partitions.

Comment: But is it possible to rescue just image files (jpg, png and others)?

Comment: There is an option in which you can list all the files in the partition and then manually select the files you want to recover

Comment: Ok I will try that out...